# How can I get number output in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

```
import sympy as sym
x,pw,f=sym.symbols('x,pw,f')
Ori=sym.exp((-(x)**2) / (2*(pw / 2.35482)**2) )/(pw / 2.35482)
FT=(sym.fourier_transform(Ori,x,f))
sym.pprint(FT)
```

the output is this

[image]

I want to get just number output which doesn't have pie and exp. The output I want has a value which has that pie equals 3.14 and exp has 2.7171.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ‘evalf()’ or ‘N()’

E.g. using f=1 and pw=1

```
import sympy as sym
x,pw,f=sym.symbols('x,pw,f')
Ori=sym.exp((-(x)**2) / (2*(pw / 2.35482)**2) )/(pw / 2.35482)
FT=(sym.fourier_transform(Ori,x,f))
sym.pprint(FT.evalf(subs={f:1, pw:1}))
```

More info here: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html